# How to save AM and PM in timePicker widget after user has selected one of 'em'?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I know a lot of people would call it duplicate question but I suggest em to first read it through.

I have a timePicker widget in XML and I've set OnTimeChangedListener on it. I'm getting the user input(hour and minute I select) and saving it with sharedPreferences, which is working fine but the timePicker always shows AM even if I select PM. So I gotta know how to get what user has chosen AM or PM and save it like I saved hour and minute?

timePicker widget XML:

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Java codes:

```
// IMPLEMENTATION OF TIME PICKER'S TIME CHANGE EVENT
        timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                savedHour = hourOfDay;
                savedMinute = minute;

            }
        });



// IMPLEMENTATION OF SAVE BUTTON
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Boolean isNotification = notificationSwitch.isChecked();
                editor.putBoolean("isNotification", isNotification);
                editor.putInt("saved_hour", savedHour);
                editor.putInt("saved_minute", savedMinute);
                editor.putBoolean("hasTimeSaved", true);
                editor.apply();
                finish();
            }
        });

// CHECK WHETHER TIME HAS BEEN SAVED BY THE USER OR NOT
if (preferences.getBoolean("hasTimeSaved", false)) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            timePicker.setHour(preferences.getInt("saved_hour", 11));
            timePicker.setMinute(preferences.getInt("saved_minute", 11));
        }else {
            timePicker.setCurrentHour(preferences.getInt("saved_hour", 11));
            timePicker.setCurrentMinute(preferences.getInt("saved_minute", 11));
        }
    }
```

I've tried setIs24Hour to true and it was working fine but I didn't like the look of my time picker's widget, so I don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

Android's `TimePicker` is 24-hour internally so in `OnTimeChangedListener` you should be getting 0~23. Likewise, calling `setHour()` with a value from 12 to 23 should show PM on the time picker. I've just tested it on my phone and everything is working as expected.

Comment: Here's the activity: https://pastebin.com/rycyAYzX
The layout is just a `TimePicker` element.